# Numbering child elements in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, and I'm confused about how it's supposed to work.

I want to make a little assessment app with questions, sections, and a totals section.

I marked up what I want inside of a home page component like this:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    public render() {
        return <SurvivalTest>
            <Section title="Requirements">
                <Question>
                    Does the project have a clear, unambiguous vision statement
                    or mission statement?
                </Question>
                <Question>
                    Do all team members believe the vision is realistic?
                </Question>
                <Question>
                    Does the project have a business case that details the
                    business benefit and how the benefit will be measured?
                </Question>
            </Section>
            <Section title="Planning">
                <Question>
                    Does the project have a detailed, written Software
                    Development Plan?
                </Question>
                <Question>
                    Were the schedule and budget estimates officially updated
                    at the end of the most recently completed phase?
                </Question>
                <Question>
                    Does the project have detailed, written architecture and
                    design documents?
                </Question>
            </Section>
            <TotalsSection />
        </SurvivalTest>;
    }
}
```

The questions each have 4 possible answers, scored 0-3.  The answers are the same for all questions and they are: "No", "Not really", "Probably", and "Yes".  The Section component the table element and labels for the answers are in the table headers.

```
export class Question extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { score: 0 };
    }

    public render() {
        return <tr>
            <td>
                <input name={'q' + ???} type="radio" onClick={() => this.setState({ score: 0 })} checked={this.state.score === 0} />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name={'q' + ???} type="radio" onClick={() => this.setState({ score: 1 })} checked={this.state.score === 1} />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name={'q' + ???} type="radio" onClick={() => this.setState({ score: 2 })} checked={this.state.score === 2} />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name={'q' + ???} type="radio" onClick={() => this.setState({ score: 3 })} checked={this.state.score === 3} />
            </td>
            <td>
                {??? + '. ' + this.props.children}
            </td>
        </tr>;
    }
}
```

How do I number the questions automatically?  I want to display a question number before the question text, and I also want to name the input fields based on the question number (e.g. q1, q2, etc.)

Can each Question component ask its parent (Section) component for its question number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good choice to use react.js ;-)

You have encountered a first huge problem with react.js standalone: You need to bubble a lot of information between your component layers up and down. After time it becomes so complex that you'll reach a point you just want to f*** that s*** off.

So let's first talk about how to separate the business logic from the view components so that you then can then handle state changes.

I will use React Baobab to handle the application state.

```
// state.js
import Baobab from "baobab";

const state = new Baobab({
    name:      "MySurvivalTest",
    structure: {
        sections: [{
            id:        0
            title:     "MyFirstSection",
            questions: [{
                id:    0,
                items: [{
                    id:    0,
                    name:  "q1",
                    value: 0
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },
    answers: []
});

export default state;
```

This is the place where all your application data is stored. In my example your test contains one section with one question that has one item and no question is answered yet (answers is empty).

Before we build the components let's build the application logic.

```
// actions/Question.js
export const answer = (state, questionId, value) => {
    state.select("answers").set(
        state.get("answers")
            .filter(x => x.questionId !== questionId)
            .concat([{ questionId, value }])
    );
};
```

The Question.answer function adds answers to the state mentioned before.

So now it's time to build the components very quickly and consistent.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { branch as BaobabBranch } from "baobab-react/higher-order";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

@BaobabBranch({
    structure: ["structure"]
})
export default class Home extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        structure: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        answers:   PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    public render() {
        return (<SurvivalTest>
            { this.props.structure.sections.map(section =>
                <Section
                    title={section.title}
                >
                { section.questions.map(question => 
                    <Question structure={question} />
                )}
                </Section>
            )}
        </SurvivalTest>);
    }
}

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { branch as BaobabBranch } from "baobab-react/higher-order";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { answer } from "../actions/Question";

@BaobabBranch({
    answers: ["answers"]
})
export default class Question extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        question: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        answers:  PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };

    onClick(id, event) {
        this.props.dispatch(answer, id, value);
    }

    public render() {
        return this.props.question.items.map(item => 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input
                        name={item.name}
                        checked={this.props.answers.find(x => x.questionId === this.props.question.id).value === item.value}
                        onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, this.props.question.id, item.value)}
                    />
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

Ok this is much input. So what's the Baobab annotation? The Baobab annotation can be seen as a listener. So Home listens on structure while Question listens on answers. Each time a listened attribute is changed by an action (we just have 1 action - the answer action) all listening components trigger a rerender with the new data.

So if you now trigger a click action on the input field the answer action is triggered (The dispatch function is automatically added to your component if you use the Baobab annotation. It binds the state to the action (first argument) and adds all other arguments behind.). The answer action causes a state change on answers which then forces a rerender of Questions.

Disclaimer: I have not tested the code so maybe some parts are missing or wrong. But I hope you get a deeper understanding of how to build an application with React.js (and Baobab).

Comment: Thank you for working so hard on your answer.  I was hoping to keep the tags intact that I had in my question and not scatter them throughout a bunch of different classes, but I guess React doesn't work that way.

Comment: Working with React means to build well-defined components that you can reuse everywhere. This is the reason I'm such a big fan of React. It works so much better than many other approaches.

Comment: To separate logic from view is not a React thing, it's an architectural decision that I propose. Not just when using React, but always if this is a choice.

Comment: Oh, I'm all for it, believe me.  I'm just trying to get my head around the method of doing it.

Comment: If you need any more advice you can of course write an email and get in touch with me

Answer (score 0):

Have a inline logic in jsx .Some thing like

```
render() {
  let questionIndex = 0
  return ( < div > {
      json.map((element, index) => {
        //Can create jsx according to need
        questionIndex += 1
        return ( < div key = {
            questionIndex
          } >
          < p >
          Question number {
            questionIndex
          } < /p> < Options / >
          < Input / >
          < AnyOtherComponent / >
          < /<div>

        )
      })
    } < /div>

  )

}
```

Please let me know if that helped. It may give you some hints

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand.  I don't know anything about json.map.